# The results could not be loaded in Post Object field in ACF

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

There is a page with ACF fields. There are fields of type Post Object. In half the cases, when expanding the list of post objects, the message "The results could not be loaded" appears in these fields.

I've noticed that when the list loads normally, it sends a POST request to ajax.php. When an error message occurs, a POST request is made to the post.php file with a 302 redirect and then the edit.php file is called. On the browser's Network tab in the edit.php preview, I see the message "Session expired. Please log in again."
Clearing cookies and cache did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Probably just need to increase your max_input_vars variable.  Open up your .htaccess file and add `php_value max_input_vars 2000`